# R barplot: Columns of different height

Tags: r, bar-chart

Imagine I want to create a bar chart from a contingency table. The data is as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"Age    Gender  Mobile
13  Male    1
14  Female  1
18  Female  1
13  Male    1
13  Female  1
14  Female  0
16  Male    1
16  Female  0
16  Male    0
20  Male    0
14  Male    0
13  Female  0
25  Male    1
13  Female  0
24  Female  0"))
```

I then create the contingency table (in this case, I am just interested in a subset of the data):

```
df$Gender<-factor(df$Gender)
df$Mobile<-factor(df$Mobile)
table1<-prop.table(xtabs(~Mobile+Age, df[df$Gender=="Female",]))
```

I then create the bar chart:

barplot(table1)

It does work. But the columns are not of the same height. it does not look 'nice'.

[image]

I would like to get the columns aligned. what can I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking for. Could you somehow illustrate the desired behavior? Please also see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why should the bars be the same height???

Answer (score 1):

You use `prop.table` *without* a `margin` argument, so it computes total frequencies, and not row or column frequencies. You want column frequencies to have bars the same height. Try this:

```
table1<-prop.table(xtabs(~Mobile+Age, df[df$Gender=="Female",]),margin=2)

barplot(table1)
```

[image]